# XSL Transformation - Turning a list into nested elements, How Can I do that?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, transformation

I have a bunch of messages that are in older schema version. I want to consume the messages
from the older schema and then transform them to the new schema form. I really appreciate it
if anyone can help me with this.

### My New Schema

```
<Audit>
       <time>12:35</time>
       <number>13354</number>
       <previousAudit>
               <time>2:54</time>
               <number>12667</number>
               <previousAudit>
                      <time>7:05</time>
                      <number>10659</number>       
                      <previousAudit/>
               </previousAudit>
       </previousAudit>
</Audit>       


My Old Schema
-------------

<MyAuditList>
<Audit>
       <time>12:35</time>
       <number>13354</number>      
</Audit>       
<Audit>
       <time>1:27</time>
       <number>13650</number>      
</Audit>       
<Audit>
       <time>7:05</time>
       <number>10659</number>      
</Audit>       
</MyAuditList>
```

So I want to recursively read my Old Schema (Message's Audit List and Nest it in Previous Audit form as above) , How
can I acheieve something like this in xsl ? Thank you so much in advanced for your help.

Comment: Any sorting is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="MyAuditList">
    <Audit>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Audit[1]/*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Audit[2]"/>
    </Audit>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Audit">
    <previousAudit>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Audit"/>
    </previousAudit>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Audit>
  <time>12:35</time>
  <number>13354</number>
  <previousAudit>
    <time>1:27</time>
    <number>13650</number>
    <previousAudit>
      <time>7:05</time>
      <number>10659</number>
    </previousAudit>
  </previousAudit>
</Audit>
```

---

If you have to output empty `previousAudit` use this one:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="MyAuditList">
    <Audit>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Audit[1]/*"/>
      <previousAudit>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Audit[2]"/>
      </previousAudit>
    </Audit>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Audit">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    <previousAudit>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Audit"/>
    </previousAudit>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Audit>
  <time>12:35</time>
  <number>13354</number>
  <previousAudit>
    <time>1:27</time>
    <number>13650</number>
    <previousAudit>
      <time>7:05</time>
      <number>10659</number>
      <previousAudit />
    </previousAudit>
  </previousAudit>
</Audit>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, does this xsl work if I have more elements in my auditList ? or it's fixed for this message only ?

Comment: @EmanuelSchuster, You're welcome. It will work correctly for any number of `Audit`.

Comment: Thank you Kirill. I would like to know, Do I need to put the whole template in the <previousAudit> tag in the xsl or I should put on top of the xsl and then call it by apply-template in the <previous> tag ?

Comment: I have my xslt file, where in the body of it should I place the xsl code you paste here ?

Comment: @EmanuelSchuster, It depends on your real XML and XSLT. You should try this solution. If you have any problems, create new question and post your XML there which reproduces your issue.